# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nlst'

Tags: python, ftplib

I am trying to put this into def statments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os
import sys
import paramiko
import datetime
import pickle

username = "ftp1"
password = "pass"


try:
        try:
            print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
            ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
            ftp.login(username, password)
            ftp.cwd('Dir')

        except ftplib.all_errors as e:
            print(e)
except ftp.login as s:
    print (s)

files = []

try:
        files = ftp.nlst()
except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
   if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
        print "No files in this directory"
   else:
        raise

for f in files:
   print f
```

----------------------revised--------------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os
import sys
import paramiko
import datetime
import pickle
import ftplib as ftp


hostname = "0.0.0.0"
password = "pass"
username = "ftp1"

def connect():
    try:
        print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
        ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
        ftp.login(username, password)

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print(e)

connect()


def list_files():

    files = []

    try:
             files = ftp.nlst()
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
        if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
        else:
             raise

    for f in files:
       print f

list_files()
```

---

Successful with the first function created:

```
def connect():
    try:
        print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
        ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
        ftp.login(username, password)

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print(e)

connect()
```

-----------------------get error on second def statement----------------

```
def list_files():

    files = []

    try:
             files = ftp.nlst()
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
        if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
        else:
             raise

    for f in files:
       print f

list_files()
```

====================***AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nlst'***============

Please help me understand what I am missing here.... I am sure it is something simple.... but I am missing it....

Comment: Are you sure you pasted your latest code? Because you only have `nlst` as functions in your code here, so it shouldn't be giving you `AttributeError`...

Comment: @lucasnadalutti that's what is raised when you access whatever is not available in an object

Answer (score 0):

After `import ftplib as ftp`, `ftp` references the `ftplib` module. Since you use `ftplib` directly, you should just drop the `as ftp` from the import statement.

In addition, since you want to call `nlst`, you'll have to pass the actual `ftp` variable to `list_files`.

Comment: but how do i pass "ftp" as a variable to "list_files"? if this is a silly question please forgive

Comment: There's no such thing as a silly question. One option you have is to make `connect` return the `ftp` variable and then pass it as a parameter to the `list_files` function. Usage would then look like `ftp = connect()` then `list_files(ftp)`. Another approach would be to put both functions in a class which would have `ftp` as an attribute.

Comment: so would my def look like such:

Comment: def connect():
    try:
        print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
        ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
        ftp.login(username, password)
 ftp.connect()
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print(e)

connect()

def list_files(ftp):

    files = []

    try:
                  files = ftp.nlst()
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
        if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
        else:
             raise

    for f in files:
      print f

list_files()

Answer (score 0):

Wanna Thank Everyone who posted an Answer to help me correct my mistakes.
Was able to figure out what "Arkanosis" was suggesting to fix the errors:

One option you have is to make connect return the ftp variable and then pass it as a parameter to the list_files function. Usage would then look like ftp = connect() then list_files(ftp). Another approach would be to put both functions in a class which would have ftp as an attribute. –  Arkanosis

ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")

ftp.login(username,password)

Added ftp to each individual "def" block as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os
import sys
import paramiko
import datetime
import pickle
import ftplib as ftp


hostname = "0.0.0.0"
password = "pass"
username = "ftp"


def connect():
    try:
        print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
        ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
        ftp.login(username, password)

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print(e)

connect()

def list_files():
    try:
           ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
           ftp.login(username,password)
           files = []
           files = ftp.nlst()
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
       if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
       else:
            raise

    for f in files:
       print f

list_files()

def list_directory():
    try:
          ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
          ftp.login(username, password)
          files = []
          files = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
       if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
       else:
            raise

    for f in files:
        print file

list_directory()

def list_Upload():
    try:
          ftp = ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")
          ftp.login(username, password)
          ftp.cwd('directory')
          files = []
          files = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
       if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print "No files in this directory"
       else:
            raise

    for f in files:
        print file

list_Upload()
```

I will be converting this to a class statement in the upcoming revisions and will update the post for those who would like use this as template to help build their ftp project.

This is just very basic build to begin communicating with your FTP server as you build your final FTP script.